# Scala, Charts and Google Visualisation API

Tags: scala, charts, graph, visualization

Those anyone know of a Scala Library for Graphs / Charts or an implementation of the Google Visualisation API.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Scala is cool and all, why not use a well-established library from the Java domain? [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) comes to mind, it's very versatile and works well.

One of Scala's strengths is its interoperability with Java. Without lifting a finger, Scala programs get access to most of the wealth of libraries developed in/for Java. No need to wait for someone to re-invent the wheel in Scala for specialized solutions like these.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are a scala wrapper over JFreeCharts:
https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart
It may be more handy to use scala API's working with java-based libraries.